# Observer Cancel order Magento

Tags: php, magento, events

Hi I'm trying to add functionality when I'm canceling a order in Magento.
my config is working and when I'm cancelling a order my function gets triggered but i don't get the order dispatched to the observer.
Here are the initial code of my class.

```
class Imo_Model_Observer {

    static function exportOrder($observer)
    {
        $order= $observer->getData('entity_id');

        self::createFile($order, 'completed');
        //echo "export started";
    }
```

In this case i have tryed to get `entity_id` from the order I'm canceling but with no luck.
i would like to get the whole order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cancelling a order means actually that order state is set to "cancelled" so you need to observe the event sales_order_save_after and get the order object from event, check which was the previous state and set your own state

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i ended up with

```
  public function exportOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {
        $track = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment();
        $increment_id = $track->getOrder();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.3 there is the event `order_cancel_after`, which is dispatched after the cancellation took place.

The `cancel` method in `Magento\Sales\Model\Order` looks like this:

```php
public function cancel()
{
    if ($this->canCancel()) {
        $this->getPayment()->cancel();
        $this->registerCancellation();

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('order_cancel_after', ['order' => $this]);
    }

    return $this;
}
```